# Jupyter Notebook Kernel Disregards Kernelspec

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython, jupyter, pyenv

On a MacOS Big Sur (11.6.2), I have a global `Jupyter` instance (version `6.4.6`) installed in an isolated `pyenv` virtual environment, using Python `3.10.0`. Using my normal workflow, I created a new virtual environment (Python `3.8.12`), using `pyenv-virtualenvwrapper`. After activating the new environment, I installed `ipykernel` in it and then ran `python -m ipykernel install --user --display-name=my-new-env --name=my-new-env`. The resulting kernel was created in `Installed kernelspec my-new-env in /Users/myuser/Library/Jupyter/kernels/my-new-env`. Running `jupyter kernelspec list` correctly lists the kernelspec.

When I launch `jupyter notebook` from this new environment, and select the `my-new-kernel` from the dropdown, it still points to the Python in the Jupyter environment which is `3.10.0`, instead of `3.8.12`. This was verified by running `! python --version` and `! which python` in the notebook. Here is the contents of the `kernel.json` file, located at `/Users/myuser/Library/Jupyter/kernels/my-new-env/kernel.json`:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/Users/myuser/.virtualenvs/my-new-env/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "my-new-env",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}
```

Additionally, I also tried to use `python -m ipykernel install --prefix=/Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/jupyter3/ --display-name=my-new-env --name =my-new-env` to register the kernel and it installed the profile in a different location, `/Users/myuser/.pyenv/versions/jupyter3/share/jupyter/kernels` but behave the same way as above.

Questions:

1. With the path of the Python executable correct in the `kernel.json` file, why would the Jupyter kernel not honor it? How can I fix this situation?
2. Does Jupyter have any awareness of the virtual environment? If yes, how does it know what environment is active?

Thanks.